# Is it safe to assume "in a few weeks" is in three weeks?

Tags: grammar

I know "a few" does not have a precise meaning but why would anyone use it for two when they could use "a couple," or for four when that's just a month? So if someone is referring to a future event at a specific time, does "a few weeks" always mean three weeks?

Comment: "A few" has no specific meaning apart from 'not many', and it is definitely **not safe** to assume that 'a few weeks' means 'three weeks'.

Answer (score 2):

It has no specific meaning, and indeed the purpose for using it is because they can't, or don't want to specify an exact number of weeks.

If someone says "This will take a few weeks" it is likely that they don't know how long it will take.  They expect it will take more than a week. They expect it won't last "many" weeks (please don't ask "how many is 'many'?"!) It might last 2, or 3, or 4 or 5 weeks, and *they don't know*.  That's why they say "a few".

If someone knows it will take exactly three weeks, they are more likely to say "three weeks" instead of "a few weeks".